# Optimize a timberman bot in Python with Pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

i try to make a timberman game from the game "timberman" using python and the lib pyautogui

My thought process were to select a pixel without three and save the color of it and if the color change on that pixel that's mean i need to click on the others side, but it doesn't working well, or very slow because if i want to go faster after the clicking the branch isn't at the right position instantly, so i need to wait and it take so long.

```
from turtle import left
from webbrowser import get
import pyautogui
import win32api, win32con
import time
import keyboard 

time.sleep(3)

def get_pixel_color_left(x, y):
        pixel_color = pyautogui.pixel(x, y)
        return pixel_color
x_position_left = 794
y_position_left = 661
left_colors = get_pixel_color_left(x_position_left, y_position_left)

x_position_right = 1096
y_position_right = 665

def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    
    
while(True):
    current_left_color = get_pixel_color_left(x_position_left, y_position_left)
    if current_left_color == left_colors:
        click(x_position_left, y_position_left) 
        time.sleep(0.15)
    else:
        click(x_position_right, y_position_right) 
        time.sleep(0.15)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
        print("stop.")
        break
```

this is my code if someone know how i can make it better

i tried to slowdown the program but i'm just loosing really fast then.